# Share 100vh between div and position:sticky navbar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to share the initial visible area of my page between a slideshow and my navbar like the below diagram which will then **stick at the top** when you scroll down the document. This is where I've run into issues.

I've tried doing something like `height: 90vh` for my slideshow and `height: 10vh` for my navbar but I want the website to be dynamic and able to fit to most resolutions until you hit cellphone level or at least like 200% zoom on Microsoft edge wherein another stylesheet will be used.

I've also tried placing them within the same div, setting `height: 90%` for the slideshow and `height: auto` for the navbar. This worked best in terms of how dynamic it is but the `position: sticky` obviously didn't work because it only traverses the height of the parent div.

The one that works best is setting the slideshow height to `height: 90vh` and allowing the navbar to go accordingly. It kinda sorta works but not nearly good enough for me.

The navbar *has* to initially be at the bottom then stick to the top. If possible I'd rather have a purely CSS solution, but I am open to javascript. Though I'd rather have pure javascript as opposed to jQuery but if it's well explained I'm okay with it.

[image: This is a diagram of what I'm trying to do]

The actual question is: **How do I make my navbar and my slideshow share the initial visible height dynamically?**

Here is all the relevant code:

```css
        #container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        height: 100vh;
    }
    .slideshow-base {
        flex-grow: 1;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
    }
    .slideshow-container {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .Slides {
        position: absolute;
        transform: translateX(-100%);
        transition: transform 2s;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
    }
    .Slides-Images {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
    }
    .navbar-base {
        font-weight: bold;
        z-index: 2;
        font-variant: small-caps;
        height: 100%;
        width: auto;
        top: 0px;
        background-color: rgba(50, 64, 147, 0.9);
        display: block;
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(226, 208, 0);
    }
```

```html
        <div id="container"> 
        <!--Slideshow-->
        <div class="slideshow-base" style="background-color: rgb(50, 64, 147); height: 90vh">
          <div class="slideshow-container">
    
            <div class="Slides">
              <img src="~/Images/Slideshow/Gallery-1.jpg" class="Slides-Images">
            </div>
    
            <div class="Slides">
              <img src="~/Images/Slideshow/Gallery-2.jpg" class="Slides-Images">
            </div>
    
            <div class="Slides">
              <img src="~/Images/Slideshow/Gallery-3.jpg" class="Slides-Images">
            </div>
    
            <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
            <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
    
            <div class="dot-base">
              <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)">&#5867;</span>
              <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)">&#5867;</span>
              <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)">&#5867;</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    
        <hr />
    
        <!--Sticky Navbar-->
        <div class="navbar-base" style="width: 100%; height: auto; position: sticky;">
          <ul>
            <li class="navbar-button" style="display: inline-block;"> @Html.ActionLink("main page", "MainPage", "Home") </li>
            <li class="navbar-button" style="display: inline-block;">
              @Html.ActionLink("about", "About", "About")
              <ul class="navbar-ddmenu">
                <li class="navbar-ddcontent" style="display: inline-block;">@Html.ActionLink("academy", "Academy", "About")</li>
                <li class="navbar-ddcontent" style="display: inline-block;">@Html.ActionLink("the club", "DKClub", "About")</li>
                <li class="navbar-ddcontent" style="display: inline-block;">@Html.ActionLink("taebo", "TaeBo", "About")</li>
                <li class="navbar-ddcontent" style="display: inline-block;">@Html.ActionLink("founders and staff", "Staff", "About")</li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="navbar-button" style="float:right"> @Html.ActionLink("contacts", "Contacts")</li>
            <li class="navbar-button" style="float:right"> @Html.ActionLink("gallery", "Gallery")</li>
            <li class="navbar-button" style="float:right"> @Html.ActionLink("shop dk", "Index", "Shop")</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: flex is your friend

Comment: You can try CSS-Grid.

Comment: @gavgrif Which one would you guys recommend? I'll only be using one of the two for the first part of the document, and if i do return to it, my use of them will be incredibly sparse. Also could you guys give me a run down on how I would go about it?

Comment: @WaleedIqbal see above comment :)

Comment: If your project is mostly likely to expand in future, then IMO, use CSS-Grid. If its likely to stay as it is, use FlexBox.

Comment: @Pete no let me update the question to hopefully clear some of the ambiguity. I'll also post the relevant parts of my code.

Comment: @Pete Is that better?

Comment: @WaleedIqbal will what you're suggesting be like the below? It's going to make `position: sticky` redundant wouldn't it? The navbar will just end up in another container and it won't stick to the top after I scroll down.

Comment: You can make it absolute, and adjust its position accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I would use a flexbox approach for your initial view, then a bit of js to add a class on scroll:

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  var nav = document.getElementById('nav');
  var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  
  if (scrollTop > 100) {               // not sure how much you want it to scroll before it is made sticky
    nav.classList.add("fixed");
  } else {
    nav.classList.remove("fixed");
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  
  height:200vh; /* just so there is some scrolling */
}
.container {
  height:100vh;  
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}

.slideshow-base {
  flex-grow:1;    /* this will make shadow base take the rest of the available height to start with */
}

.fixed {
  position:fixed; 
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="slideshow-base" style="background-color: rgb(50, 64, 147); height: 90vh">
    <div class="slideshow-container">

      <div class="Slides">
        <img src="~/Images/Slideshow/Gallery-1.jpg" class="Slides-Images">
      </div>

      <div class="Slides">
        <img src="~/Images/Slideshow/Gallery-2.jpg" class="Slides-Images">
      </div>

      <div class="Slides">
        <img src="~/Images/Slideshow/Gallery-3.jpg" class="Slides-Images">
      </div>

      <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
      <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

      <div class="dot-base">
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)">&#5867;</span>
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)">&#5867;</span>
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)">&#5867;</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <hr />

  <!--Sticky Navbar-->
  <div id="nav" class="navbar-base">
    <ul>
      <li class="navbar-button" style="display: inline-block;"> @Html.ActionLink("main page", "MainPage", "Home") </li>
      <li class="navbar-button" style="display: inline-block;">
        @Html.ActionLink("about", "About", "About")
        <ul class="navbar-ddmenu">
          <li class="navbar-ddcontent" style="display: inline-block;">@Html.ActionLink("academy", "Academy", "About")</li>
          <li class="navbar-ddcontent" style="display: inline-block;">@Html.ActionLink("the club", "DKClub", "About")</li>
          <li class="navbar-ddcontent" style="display: inline-block;">@Html.ActionLink("taebo", "TaeBo", "About")</li>
          <li class="navbar-ddcontent" style="display: inline-block;">@Html.ActionLink("founders and staff", "Staff", "About")</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="navbar-button" style="float:right"> @Html.ActionLink("contacts", "Contacts")</li>
      <li class="navbar-button" style="float:right"> @Html.ActionLink("gallery", "Gallery")</li>
      <li class="navbar-button" style="float:right"> @Html.ActionLink("shop dk", "Index", "Shop")</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: One question: on the `<div class="slideshow-base">` is the `style="height: 90vh"` supposed to be there?

Comment: ah no, you can remove that (copy and paste error) - the `flex-grow:1` will make the base fill the rest of the height

Comment: okay I've just added the rest of my code because `flex-grow=1` made the slideshow disappear. I applied it to both `slideshow-base` and `slideshow-container`. The reason being it didn't effect anything when i added it to `slideshow-base`

Comment: did you do = or colon - it seems to be working in the snippet above

Comment: lmao its `flex-grow:1` i just checked,  just to reiterate it should be just in slideshow-base right?

Comment: Yes but you also need the flex container (your snippet seems to be missing it) - flex grow will only work if the parent element is flex

Comment: I've added an ID called `container` with `display: flex; flex-direction: column` and `height: 100vh`. I'll add that to the snippet as well

Comment: note that if i change the height of the slideshow-container everything adjusts.

Comment: you have a height of 20vh on your container? that means it only takes 20% of the screeen (including your nav so your slideshow is only going to be very small)

Comment: that was to test that the container is working, I reset the `height: 100vh` and right now the slideshow is again taking up 100% of the screen. When I make the height > 100%, e.g 80% in the `slideshow-container` the flexbox works

Comment: Sorry, I'm really not understanding your problem - is it too big, or not showing?

Comment: Ey I really suck at asking questions. Here it goes:

Comment: Right now the `#container` is set to `height: 100vh`. The slideshow takes up the entirety of this 100vh. However, when I change the `height` value of the `.slideshow-container` class. Your solution works, but there is space between the slideshow, and the navbar.

Comment: ok so your slideshow doesn't want to take up the rest of the screen - you want it to be a certain height and then the navbar should fill the rest of the space?

Comment: other way around. The solution you offered was on the right track. I want the navbar to fill out all the space it needs and the slideshow to fill out the rest. But right now the slideshow is pushing the navbar _outside_ of the 100vh.

Comment: hmmm, may be because your images are too tall (or you have't removed the margin on the body)

Comment: I've got a `* {}` in my CSS removing all padding and margins from the document. Shouldn't the `object-fit: cover` line get rid of the image size issues? It cuts out anything that's too tall.

Comment: only if your browser isn't ie or edge!

Comment: I've just tried it in Chrome but the same thing happens.

Comment: Whatever the problem is, it's because of the `slideshow-container` class

Comment: There is a space caused by the hr but not sure what to suggest as I can't replicate the problem - if I remove thew `height: 90vh ` inline style, everything works as I would expect

Comment: Okay I fixed it! I set the display of the `slideshow-base` to flex as well and set `flex-grow: 1` on the `slideshow-container` and it works!! Sorry for taking up so much of your time. I super appreciate it though!

Comment: Nice, glad you got it to work - you may want to test in safari though as I've had problems with nested flex items in safari

Answer (score 2):

Use CSS Grids

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#container {
  width: 100vw;
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 90vh 10vh;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

#container>div {
  background: #999;
}
```

```html
<section id="container">
  <div>Sticky</div>
  <div>NavBar</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Won't this solution just make the `position: sticky` redundant? I want my navbar to stick to the top after you scroll down a bit.

Comment: Oh ok. Yes that would be redundant. I originally thought your question was to have the nav bar sticky at bottom. If I understand correctly you want the navbar to be at bottom on page load and stick to the top after you scroll?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably wrap those 2 elements in a wrapper (and optionally give it a height) and use flexbox to make them share space.

In the example below, the slideshow will always cover 90% of the wrapper's height and nav will cover 10% of it.

```css
.slideshow,
.nav {
  border: 2px solid #000
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 90vh
}
   
.nav {
  /* An arbitrary value to start with */
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.slideshow {
  /* Grow this element 9 times more than the other element. */
  flex-grow: 9;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="slideshow">
    Slideshow content
  </div>

  <nav class="nav">
    Navigation content
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: I think this is also gonna make `position: sticky` redundant won't it> the navbar is going to have to stick to the top of the page after scrolling down

Comment: You're still going to have to specify that the nav should stick to the top when its top touches the viewport if that's what you're asking. So yeah, `position:sticky` would be redundant.

Comment: that means javascript D_:

Comment: The CSS grids solution will also force you to use JS :)